# How to restore default value of text field in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, restore

I have a page with a table having some `<input type="text">` fields. I have a button next to each field. I allow user to change the text of input fields. But when the user click the button next to input field, the corresponding input field's value need to be restored to default (previous) value.

I tried to make an array with index as input field's name. This array can store default values, and can be retrieved easily and restored to their corresponding fields. I tried to do this using `keyup(function()`, but I know that this triggers each time key is pressed.

Here is my HTML;

```
<input class="zx" type="text" name="qwer" value="Google" /><button class="cncl">X</button><br />
<input class="zx" type="text" name="qwer" value="Yahoo" /><button class="cncl">X</button><br />
<input class="zx" type="text" name="qwer" value="Bing" /><button class="cncl">X</button><br />
<input class="zx" type="text" name="qwer" value="Ask" /><button class="cncl">X</button><br />
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/R3Leq/)** is the fiddle.

How can I restore the default values to the fields?

Comment: what do you mean by previous value? the original value when the input was created

Comment: Why not just `$('form')[0].reset()`?

Comment: why dont you use placeholder attribute and do your form processing after checking if the submitted value has value or not

Answer (score 6):

Try this, use `.attr('value')` to get the default value:

```
$('.cncl').on('click', function () {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).prev().attr('value'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Leq/2/)

Comment: You'll need to use `.prevAll('.zx:first')` then like this http://jsfiddle.net/VQE6b/3/

Comment: I get `function (){        return this.defaultValue;    }` as value :(

Comment: Good solution. Its working! and thank you for the demo. very helpful +++

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [defaultValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#defaultValue) property of the input element

```
$('.cncl').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().val(function(){
        return this.defaultValue;
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VQE6b/)

Comment: This seems to be the "cleanest" way to do it. I initially thought about saving it to a variable and then restoring it but it seems that would be more work than neccesary.

Comment: Is there any way to implement the same using class names?

Comment: what do you mean by class names

Comment: I mean, how can I implement this in this fiddle (I slightly changed your fiddle, added one more button) http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/VQE6b/2/

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ can you wrap each set of controls in another element

Comment: I dont know, when I use this in my page (not fiddle), the input field gets value `function (){          return this.defaultValue;      }` :(

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similair in the past. I stored the default value in an attribute of the html-tag itself.

```
<input class="zx" type="text" name="qwer" default-value="Google" value="Google" />
```

When you like to restore it you can execute

```
$('selector').val($('selector').attr('default-value'));
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. It allows the developer to set a default value without that being the initial value. It will be confusing though since I can't imagine a situation where one would want this functionality. Still +1.

Comment: In my case it was in a form with a lot of inputs with values from server-side. Then when the user changed values he/she could click undo to restore to the value to the one saved in db.